# Suppose I want to create a "stored function" for MYSQL. Where do I wrote it? Which file?

Tags: mysql, database, function

Of course, I could go into mysql console and type the Function. But what if I want to store it for future use? What do I do?

Comment: Which Operating System are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good tutorial here:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3525581/MySQL-Stored-Procedures-Part-1.htm

You need to use [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html).  Once written, these are stored in the database along with your tables.  They can be invoked using the `CALL <procedure>` statement.

Here's an example procedure that populates `table1` with random values:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS autofill//
CREATE PROCEDURE autofill()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    WHILE i < 20000 DO
        INSERT INTO table1 (size) VALUES (FLOOR((RAND() * 1000)));
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Once the procedure has been written, it is called like this:

```
CALL autofill();
```

Answer (score 1):

Most projects have an SQL file to initialize the database from scratch. This way, one can set up the application database by simply running this SQL file. Your CREATE PROCEDURE/FUNCTION query would also go in this file.

Comment: my.cnf? how does the syntax go?

Comment: Not `my.cnf`. Usually you have something like `install.sql`, which you use to create database for new instalation -- `create table` statements and so on. This is also a good place for stored procedures.